# Spring Batch not finding global singleton scoped beans in web application - what is wrong?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring web application which registers multiple spring batch jobs for lengthy background processing at launch time. As near as I can tell, the spring-batch contexts are not aware of the singletons declared in the root AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext bean, so multiple copies of complex-to-initialize beans are being instantiated for every job both at initial application load time and again at execution time.

I have determined that in `AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean()` the bean is being correctly identified as a singleton, but for some reason the bean factory for the job is unaware of the bean factory for the parent context.

I have refactored some of the beans as Application scoped, but the application scope bean is (apparently) not legal in the spring batch context.

Either I am grossly misunderstanding something about spring scopes, or there is something out of kilter with my initialization of the spring-batch elements (code below). I am leaning towards both, as the one would lead to the other.

As I understand Spring scopes, I should see something like this, with each child scope being able to see singletons defined in the parent scope:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext (web application context)
        |
        v
ResourceXmlApplicationContext (1 per registered job)
        |
        v
ResourceXmlApplicationContext (1 per registered step)
```

Initialization code in question:

```
@Component("mySingletonScopedBean")
@Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
@Order(1)
public class MySingletonScopedBean {
    // getters, setters, etcetera
}


// EDIT: Added in response to comment below
@Autowired
public ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean
public ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean () throws IOException
{
    String resourcePath = somePath "*.xml";

    logger.trace("classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean()  :: {} ", resourcePath);
    Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources(resourcePath);


    ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean bean = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean ();
    bean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    bean.setResources(resources);

    return bean;
}

@Bean
public AutomaticJobRegistrar automaticJobRegistrar() throws IOException, Exception {

    ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean c = classpathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean ();

    AutomaticJobRegistrar automaticJobRegistrar = new AutomaticJobRegistrar();
    automaticJobRegistrar.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    automaticJobRegistrar.setApplicationContextFactories(c.getObject());
    automaticJobRegistrar.setJobLoader(jobLoader());

    return automaticJobRegistrar;
}

@Bean
public JobLoader jobLoader() {
    DefaultJobLoader jobLoader = new DefaultJobLoader(jobRegistry(), stepRegistry());
    return jobLoader;
}

@Bean
public StepRegistry stepRegistry() {
    MapStepRegistry stepRegistry = new MapStepRegistry();
    return stepRegistry;
}

@Bean
public JobRegistry jobRegistry() {
    JobRegistry jobRegistry = new MapJobRegistry();
    return jobRegistry;
}
```

---

Edit: Closing

The whole spring environment initialization was messed up.

I'm saving my rants about the "clean" injection model and what a pain it is to figure things out when they break for a massive blog post after this project.

Comment: It is not apparent where you get your `applicationContext`. Also note that factory beans might return beans that need some postprocessing. So by calling directly `getObject` you might be skipping some of those.

Comment: applicationContext is (confirmed via debugger) as the root application context of the application, which is an AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, injected by the Spring webcontext initialization.  What is the correct pattern for configuring this AutomaticJobRegistrar ?

Comment: Why are you creating an `applicationContext` per step (or job for that matter)?

Comment: What I'm aiming for is to refactor this hacked codebase into something resembling your 2013 demo from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU

Comment: I have inherited much of this code base, and I know it is not right or I wouldn't be going through this exercise. Are you saying that the use of the ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean  to load the job xml is where the issue lies?